# how large should a map be in blender

Tags: maps, models, 3d-meshes, blender

I'm learning blender and am wondering what size(blender units) I should be making my characters and maps. should i consider 1 blender unit as 1 inch, foot, meter or does it not not matter?

Answer (score 6):

The build-in physics engine assumes 1 BU (Blender Unit) = 1 meter. However, you can use whatever you like, and since Blender 2.5 you can also set an explicit conversion to real-world units (properties editor -> scene tab -> units panel). Keep in mind what kind of values your game engine expects, too - most exporters can re-scale the model during the export (same for importers), but not all of them do.

Whatever your choice is, keep in mind that the practical *smallest* unit you can work with is 0.001 BU (Blender will happily record and create smaller or more precise values, but will *not* display them to not clutter the UI), and that the maximum clip distance is 5000 BU - anything bigger will be hard to work with.

If you want to model mostly human-sized entities, including clothing and most tools for such, it makes sense to have 1 BU be equal to 1 mm. If you're more comfortable with "imperial" sizes roughly the same scale would be using 1/20th or 1/24th of an inch. This will make the smallest features you'll likely care about be about 1 BU in size and - for comparison - human hair have 0.01 to 0.2 BU in diameter.

For typical architecture, 1BU = 1m (or one yard for imperial units) will work fine. This will allow you to easily model almost every building (excluding some bridges) and vehicle built to date.

Comment: does size effect performance when the models are loaded in a game as ogre3d or a something similar?

Comment: @yamikoWebs: No. It might affect *precision* though if you end up with a lot of subnormal floating point numbers for coordinates. But then, that would require you to set up 1 BU = 1 light year and then model human-sized items with it.